How to remove rock hard caulking on bathtub
i am trying to remove old caulk. The caulking removal tool doesnt work and the box cutter isnt helping. The caulk has really solidified. Any tips on how to remove would be greatly appreciated.


Have you tried a razor scraper, used as basically a chisel?

That probably it not caulk, it's grout.  Grout dries hard and need t be broken to be removed.  Maybe just try a bleach solution to clean the mold, as I believe that is your goal.

Once cleaned, it does look like it needs to be caulked, though. Removing it would be ideal. A wider shot would help determine that.
